# Cordova, changing the colour - swipe up - space on app

Tags: iphone, cordova, plugins, uiwebview, footer

can anyone tell me how to change the colour at the bottom of an iPhone app that has the swipe horizontal bar?  So I can have it the same colour as the header/footer bars.

I have included an image to show the area I am talking about. Alternatively is there a plugin available for this?

Many thanks.

[Iphone Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBZsF.png)

Comment: Android or iOS? Your screen shot is iOS but the rest of the question doesn't say which. It's not necessarily the same on each. On iOS, using WkWebview, you set viewport-fit=cover in your viewport meta declaration. Look it up. You'll find apple docs. How it's done for Android now that it supports gestures, and has made the lower nav bar option, is an open question for me.